# git fetch only tip of branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

```
git init
git remote add production "ssh://domain.com/foo.git/"
git fetch origin
npm install --production --silent
```

the problem is that `git fetch` seems to be fetching a lot of commits.

I only want to fetch the tip of the master branch from the origin remote. Does anyone know to fetch just the latest commit from a certain branch?

Comment: See "shallow clone"; note that `git fetch` allows `--depth` as well.

Comment: yeah I looked at the `git fetch` docs again and yeah

Answer (score 3):

Since you're fetching the changes from a remote source, you can run this one-liner:

`git clone ssh://domain.com/foo.git --depth=1`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
git fetch origin master --depth=1
```

seems to work